# Access Google Task API Ruby/RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-tasks-api

And How can I access  Google Task API to get/update the google task list by ruby/RoR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no official Ruby client by Google at this point. However the API is set up to be restful and building a small wrapper around it shouldn't pose too much of a problem.

It seems that [somebody](https://github.com/jayshepherd/google_tasks_api) already started development on a ruby client, perhaps you can join forces and build it together.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the client you're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/

Tasks is not explicitly listed but this client should work.

~~Jenny

Comment: that client doesn't seem to include tasks api

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing (and as of Dec 1 2011) the Tasks API is supported: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/SupportedAPIs